# AWS - How does ec2 automatically know to use dynamodb?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I setup a Linux ec2, and got WordPress installed. After a few modifications to the site, I started getting errors like my site wouldn't load, and my table I setup in dynamodb I named testdb was getting over 250 requests for the last 5 minutes. I even created two other tables, and I was even getting errors that those databases were getting high r/w requests.

[Alarm](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1eQrD3UKsY7U3NyQXZMdlJRZ00/view?usp=sharing)

I never specified to use those databases in dynamodb, so how did my ec2 know to use that db? And how do I change what database or table WordPress or future apps use? Isn't that a security flaw if my ec2 can access any database it wants without asking me which one?

Comment: You're definitely confusing MySQL with DynamoDB here.

Comment: EC2 isn't automatically connecting to any databases. You have to configure your software to know what database to hit. Also WordPress doesn't use DynamoDB, it uses MySQL, so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why then would cloudwatch tell me my dynamodb database I named testdb is having r/w requests over 250? When I am only using wordpress on this ec2?

Comment: Here are some pics. [link1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1eQrD3UKsY7Sm9rc2ZmWEM0Sms/view?usp=sharing) [link2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1eQrD3UKsY7U3NyQXZMdlJRZ00/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those pictures are showing an ALARM setting. The alarm is configured to send a notification if the `ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits` metric exceeds 960. The graph is showing 960 because it is when the alarm will be triggered.

However, your DynamoDB table is **not currently consuming any capacity**. This is indicated by the fact that the alarm is in the `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` state, indicating that there is no metric information.

**Bottom line:** The DynamoDB table is not being used.